# Reproducing the disappearing glass experiment with normal glass

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, refraction, glass

There is a famous [disappearing glass](http://gr5.org/index_of_refraction/) experiment in which you use pyrex glass (IoR=1.47) and oils with similar IoR to create an illusion that the glass disappeared.

Is there a liquid (mixture) that can reproduce this experiment with normal glass (IoR about 1.57)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the glass rod is surrounded by a liquid that has the same index of refraction, the speed of light will not change as it enters the rod meaning there'll be no refraction. If there is no refraction, the rod will appear "invisible".
So the idea here is to get a liquid substance that has the same refractive index of glass, $n_g\approx 1.57$.

The table in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refractive_indices) lists, at *standard temperature and pressure* or STP (20$^\circ$ Celcius, 1 atmosphere pressure), the refractive index of [benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene) (C$_6$H$_6$) at $n_1 \approx 1.50$ and for [carbon disulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_disulfide) (CS$_2$) at $n_2\approx 1.63$ where$^1$ a mixture of these two liquids (or perhaps a  mixture of any of the liquids in the correct proportions) should do the trick.

But note that the [refractive index of a mixture](https://www.academia.edu/21780316/Refractive_Index_of_Liquid_Mixtures_Theory_and_Experiment) of liquids is not obtained by the simple adding together of proportional volumes (to get the required refractive index), but rather $$n_{\text mix}^{\text id} =\frac{\phi_1\phi_2(n_1 -n_2)^2}{\phi_1n_1 +\phi_2 n_2 +\sqrt{\phi_1 n_1^2 +\phi_2 n_2^2}}$$ where $n_{\text mix}^{\text id}$ is the *ideal* refractive index for the mixture, and $\phi_1 , \phi_2$ are *mixing fractions*.

$^1$ It appears as though such a mixture, or any other mixture of liquids in the list, will be non-reactive at STP, but I cannot be too sure. C$_6$H$_6$ and CS$_2$ are both clear liquids that *should* inertly mix  (but the prior is highly flammable and the latter is a neurotoxin and highly volatile!) at STP without leading to a liquid with noticeably different optical properties.